# Getting which file is open in notepad using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wmi, wmi-query

I want to figure out whether a file is open in Notepad and a File open on Adobe Reader.
 If you open task manager, Go to process tab, You can see the "Command Line" column (If not, then Go to View->Select Column) which contains EXE path and opened file's path. 
If I get this information, I can easily parse this string to get opened file name (Along with it's path -- Bonus!)

I found an [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2015/02/27/get-process-owner-and-other-info-with-wmi-and-powershell.aspx), which shows the way by PowerShell using WMI. Is there any way to do the same using Python 2.7
I know there's a WMI library for python but not able to figure out how to implement:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'notepad.exe'" | fl *
```

Comment: I don't know your exact use case but unfortunately, just checking the command line wouldn't suffice if you want to know exactly which file is currently opened by a specific process. For example, a file can be opened in notepad w/o the command-line using the `File` -> `Open` menu.

Comment: @user193130 True! Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil)

```
import psutil

for pid in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    if p.name() == "notepad.exe":
        print p.cmdline()
```